# @Ajax.BeginForm LoadingElementId does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i am having a problem displaying the loading element in my ajax request,
can anybody help?
This is my code

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Browse", "Item", new {category = "dropDownValue" }, new AjaxOptions{
  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
  HttpMethod = "GET",
  LoadingElementId = "loader",
  UpdateTargetId = "divTable"
}))
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => category, new SelectList(category), "--select a category--", new { @class = "form-control", onchange="this.form.submit()"})
}


<div id="loader" style="display:none">
    Loading...<img src="~/Content/gears.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: The code looks fine (although you should delete `new {category = "dropDownValue" }`) Are you sure you making an ajax call and not a normal submit (have you included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke hi Stephen, yes i included jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in my layout page, i don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i figured it out i replaced `onchange ="this.form.submit()"`  with `onchange = "$(form).submit()"` and i forgot to specify that my action method should return a PartialView.